# Controlling itemsep at bottom of page with enumitem

Tags: spacing, lists, page-breaking, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package to create lists of questions with space automatically left for answers.

A combination of the `itemsep` and `after` options, along with stretchable space (my document uses `\flushbottom`) does this perfectly. Except for cases when a list breaks across a page.

I think the following MWE example covers my use cases. Without altering anything in the body of the document, I'd like the following:

- `itemsep` space should be added below *Item 6*, so that there is equal space between all items on page 2 including after the item at the bottom of the page.
- Ideally, *Item 10* (currently at the bottom of the page) should be pushed to page 4, since there is not enough room to put an extra `itemsep` space in on this page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\mylen}\setlength{\mylen}{3.25cm plus 2cm minus 1cm}
\setlist[enumerate]{resume,itemsep=\mylen,after=\vspace{\mylen}}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1.
  \item Item 2.
  \item Item 3.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 4.
  \item Item 5.
  \item Item 6.
  \item Item 7.
  \item Item 8.\vspace{-1.7cm}
  \item Item 9.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 10.
  \item Item 11.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try to replace the one large vspace by a number of smaller \vspace*{..}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I'm not sure what you mean. In `after=…`? That might help if a list finishes right at a page break. But my MWE doesn't actually demonstrate that issue (though it might be an issue).

Comment: Use [`needspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) and [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and then add `before={\preto\item{\Needspace{\mylen}}}` in your `\setlist[enumerate]`?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, yes I think something like this is going to work. I'm experimenting with patching `\item` in the `before` option at present.

Comment: @DavidPurton Sorry I misread the question. I thought you want to control the space after the enumerate.

Comment: @DavidPurton Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman, I've basically gone with your answer, although at the moment I have set `itemsep=0pt` and just put a `\vspace` in the `\preto\item` macro. If I have further trouble, I'll try your suggestion of the `needspace` package (which is clever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`needspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) and [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and then add `before={\preto\item{\Needspace{\mylen}}}` in your `\setlist[enumerate]`? It seem to satisfy both the requested actions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem,needspace,etoolbox}
\newlength{\mylen}\setlength{\mylen}{3.25cm plus 2cm minus 1cm}
\setlist[enumerate]{resume,itemsep=\mylen,after=\vspace{\mylen},before={\preto\item{\Needspace{\mylen}}}}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1.
  \item Item 2.
  \item Item 3.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 4.
  \item Item 5.
  \item Item 6.
  \item Item 7.
  \item Item 8.\vspace{-1.7cm}
  \item Item 9.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 10.
  \item Item 11.
\end{enumerate}
Filler text.
\end{document}
```